# Add clickEvent to int array

Tags: android

There are three icons. I put icons on integer array. How can I give them click-listener event. **icon0,icon1,icon2 events are different**. I want to give them click event. But I can not do it. How can I give click events to icons separately

and I use wheel.gama jar and This icons are not in the xml. They are at drawable folder

```
package com.myproject.gama;

import java.util.Arrays;

import com.digitalaria.gama.wheel.Wheel;
import com.digitalaria.gama.wheel.WheelAdapter;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.View.*;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import android.util.Log;

public class SampleWheelActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = SampleWheelActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private Wheel wheel;
    public WheelAdapter<Adapter> adapter;
    private Resources res; 
    public int[] icons = { 
         R.drawable.icon1, R.drawable.icon0 , R.drawable.icon2};
    ImageView t;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        res = getApplicationContext().getResources();
        wheel = (Wheel) findViewById(R.id.wheel);       
        wheel.setItems(getDrawableFromData(icons));
        wheel.setWheelDiameter(400);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){

        for (int i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {
             t= new ImageView(SampleWheelActivity.this);
                t.setId(i);
                t.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
                    super.onResume();
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

The drawables do not have onClick-Events. You need to set the event-Listener to the Wheel (e. g. OnWheelChangedListener) and then handle the event. There you can switch on the selected Id of the wheel.

Edit:

Code:

```
wheel.addChangingListener(new OnWheelChangedListener() {
    public void onChanged(WheelView wheel, int oldValue, int newValue) {
        switch(newValue) {
            case 0:
                // icon1 is selected as it has index 0
                // do something
                break;
            case 1:
                // icon0 is selected as it has index 1
                // do something else
                break;
            case 2:
                // icon2 is selected as it has index 2
                // and again something else
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could I change it imageview

Comment: and how can I set the event-listener to the wheel.. :(

Comment: added example for your init-Method

Comment: says.. setOnWheelChangedListener is undefined

Comment: corrected the code. The Wheel can have several listeners, so it is `addChangingListener` instead. I did not check before writing the code. The method is declared in the class, so you will find the correct methods for the other Listeners there as well.

Comment: Bıt ı can reach icons at array how can ı reach them

Comment: Your icons are added to the Wheel in order 1, 0, 2, so in your EventListener you have to check the newValue, if the newValue is 0, your Image 1 is selected (first item in your array), if newValue is 1, your Image 0 is selected (second item), if newValue is 2, image 2 is selected

Comment: do you give me any algorithm :((

Comment: which part could I put which method

Comment: where I have added the comments, I made it more clear again. When I look at your questions, you should start over with simple Android tutorials for ListViews They are much better explained than the custom Wheel-class but follow the same ideas.

Comment: I try to import it could I use addOnLayoutChangeListener